# optimize populating 3 comboboxes with many items

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to design a page using MVC4 Razor, with three comboboxes into it in which I have to populate them with aprox 30,000 to 50,000 items at page load time and at same time. According to your experience, how can I do to optimize populating this items to avoid user has to wait long time page be rendered?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot! is in C# the development.

Comment: if a combobox contain 30-50 thousand elements the user experience will be really poor.  
What kind of data is there? You sure it has to be display as combobox? I rather use jQuery autocomplete where an ajax request filter the items and only return top 100 record. And I think it's still lot and the user has a really hard job to find the correct value.

Comment: Data comes from database table. And what about virttualization mechanism? is it too complicate?